# how to add complementary intervals in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say that I have a `signal` of 100 samples `L=100`

In this signal I found some intervals that I label as "OK". The intervals are stored in a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
c = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[10,26],[50,84]]),columns=['Start','End'])
c['Value']='OK'
```

How can I add the complementary intervals in another dataframe in order to have something like this

```
 d = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0,9],[10,26],[27,49],[50,84],[85,100]]),columns=['Start','End'])
 d['Value']=['Check','OK','Check','OK','Check']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
d = pd.merge(d, c, how='left')
d['Value'] = d['Value'].fillna('Check')
print (d)
   Start  End  Value
0      0    9  Check
1     10   26     OK
2     27   49  Check
3     50   84     OK
4     85  100  Check
```

EDIT:

You can use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) with [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html), [`numpy.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) and `DataFrame` constructor for new `df`. Last need   [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by `dict` for column for replace:

```
s = np.sort(np.concatenate([[0], c['Start'].values, c['End'].values + 1]))
e = np.sort(np.concatenate([c['Start'].values - 1, c['End'].values, [100]]))
d =  pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([s,e]), columns=['Start','End'])
d = pd.merge(d, c, how='left').fillna({'Value':'Check'})
print (d)
   Start  End  Value
0      0    9  Check
1     10   26     OK
2     27   49  Check
3     50   84     OK
4     85  100  Check
```

EDIT1 :

For `d` was added new values by `loc`, rehape to `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html). Last create `df` back by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
b = c.copy()
max_val = 100
min_val = 0
c.loc[-1, 'Start'] = max_val + 1
a = c[['Start','End']].stack(dropna=False).shift().fillna(min_val - 1).astype(int).unstack()
a['Start'] = a['Start'] + 1
a['End'] = a['End'] - 1
a['Value'] = 'Check'
print (a)
    Start  End  Value
 0      0    9  Check
 1     27   49  Check
-1     85  100  Check

d = pd.concat([b, a]).sort_values('Start').reset_index(drop=True)
print (d)
   Start  End  Value
0      0    9  Check
1     10   26     OK
2     27   49  Check
3     50   84     OK
4     85  100  Check
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, but my problem is that I do not have the dataframe d, I don't know how to create it starting from c

Comment: Hmmm, then it is more complicated. Please give me some time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the first Dataframe to create the second one and merge like suggested @jezrael :

```
d = pd.DataFrame({"Start":[0] + sorted(pd.concat([c.Start , c.End+1])), "End": sorted(pd.concat([c.Start-1 , c.End]))+[100]} )
d = pd.merge(d, c, how='left')
d['Value'] = d['Value'].fillna('Check')
d = d.reindex_axis(["Start","End","Value"], axis=1)
```

output

```
    Start   End Value
0   0       9   Check
1   10     26   OK
2   27     49   Check
3   50     84   OK
4   85    100   Check
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea to have first "Start" and then "End" as column?